# how to up question that has a lot of new details?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Assume you have asked question and during discussion a lot of new details were added and question become more precise and much more answerable.
However because question is old people don't pay enough attention on it. If you ask a new question (which is now much more detailed and better organized) and link your previous question people start blame you that you create duplicate question.

So how can I force people to look at my question? The only one option is bounty?

Comment: Editing a question already bumps it. A bounty is the other option. You can never *force* anyone to look at anything, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to force anybody to your question. Use positive attraction by:

- giving it a good descriptive  title
- provide an excelent body, describing the problem, giving just enough information and show your effort. But remove all clutter
- add the correct tags
- track your question and answer anything asked in comments (if relevant)
- edit strategically (puts the question back on top)
- use a bounty to get more attention to an older post